# Complex sum question

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $\omega = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})$

show that $1+\omega^h + {\omega}^{2h}+ \ldots + \omega^{(n-1)h}=0$ if $h$ is not multiple of $n$

Comment: Treat that as a geometric sum

Comment: Another way: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) : $\displaystyle e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

and summation [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Related_formulas) of Geometric Series to get $$\frac{1-w^{nh}}{1-w^h}$$

as $h$ is not multiple of $\displaystyle n, w^h\ne1$

and $w^{nh}=(w^n)^h=\left(\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}\right)^n\right)^h=\left(e^{2\pi i}\right)^h=1^h$

Comment: Related :  De Moivre's formula :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMoivresIdentity.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula